# Extjs Grid updating Issue in Date Field

Tags: date, extjs

I have 3 datefield in grid and when I am updating anything in row, it shows red mark on date field that means date fields are also modified but I am not making any change in any date field.

I tried to find out problem and I got following reason:

`context.originalValues.dateCreated : 11/10/2014
context.originalValues.dateModified : 11/10/2014
context.originalValues.lastLogin : 11/10/2014`

and

`context.newValues.dateCreated : Mon Nov 10 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
context.newValues.dateModified : Mon Nov 10 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
context.newValues.lastLogin : Mon Nov 10 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)`

so, grid shows these dates columns are updated. Is there any way to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Seems like you should go to the Sencha Forum and report a Bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue :)

The date in store was in string format so created date object in Store, and now it is working fine. I used following codes to create date object in store.

`{
    name: 'lastLogin',
    type: 'date',
    dateFormat: 'n/j/Y',
    convert: function (newValue, model) 
    {
       return new Date(model.get('lastLogin'));
    }
}`